# Getting email upon inserting rows to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I do have a google sheet where I would like to be notified with any new row/rows inserted to it.

Is there any extension which can handle that, or I should use Google Apps Script as I am new for it and never used it before.

Comment: Keep in mind that the solutions provided do not work it the row insertion is not done by a real user.  Insertions performed by scripts do not generate triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are looking for a trigger to be activated when you **insert** a new row.

- The following script will send an email when a new row is inserted in `Sheet1`. Feel free to change the name of the sheet: `sh.getName()=='Sheet1'`.

### Solution:

```
function sendEmailRow(e) {
 const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();  
 if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "example@gmail.com", 
      subject: "A new row has been added",
      body: "New row!"
    });
  }
}
```

### Installation

- Copy and Paste the above code in a blank script in the script editor (**Tools => Script editor**) and save the changes.

You need to create an **installable** `onChange` trigger for `sendEmailRow`:

- Click on: current project's triggers

[image: menu1]

- Create a new trigger and then select exactly these settings:

[image: menu2]

- Your application is ready! As soon as you insert a new row in `Sheet1`, you will send an email to the selected recipient.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marios but am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Read again the installation instructions. I **did not** say to execute it manually. I said to copy paste and save it and then create an installable trigger for it as I describe in the pictures. Then you just need to insert a new row in `Sheet1`. Please read carefully the instructions. Thing about it. This is a trigger function. You need to be notified when something changes in your sheet (in this case a row was inserted). It wouldn't make sense to have to execute it manually.

Comment: i do apologize for that. thank you. i will append now and try it. thanks a lot

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη you don't need to apologize :) sorry if it looked impolite :) I didn't mean to.

Comment: thank you Marios. it's works but i didn't get the row as a body in the email. but it's ok you helped me a lot

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I don't work for google :) but I am working with different google products :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an extension/add-on that would handle this but you could do it with an script

The below will send an email, on a trigger that alerts you as to values in column A of any new rows that have been added. It then sets a value in column c to say an email has been sent so when the script runs again it doesn't pick these up.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //<-- Change sheet name
  var rng = sh.getDataRange();
  var val = rng.getDisplayValues();
  var lr = rng.getLastRow();
  var blank = "";
  var match = false;
  var body = "Hello, "+"\n\n"+"A row with"; //<-- change to anything
  for (var i = 1; i < lr; i++) {
    if (val[i][0] != blank && val[i][2] != "Sent") { //<-- 0 refers to value in column a (A=0 B=1 C=2 etc) It also checks here column C for if it has "Sent" in it
      var bodyVal = val[i][0];
      body = body+"\n - "+bodyVal; //<-- use this to add a value from that row to email body
      match = true;
      sh.getRange(i+1,3).setValue('Sent'); //<-- where to set the "Sent" value (change above as well)
    }
  }
  body = body+"\n has been added.";
  if(match) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "mail@example.com", //<-- change email
      subject: "Reminder", //<-- email subject
      body: body
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for that helpful answer, but is that part `//<-- 0 refers to value in column a (A=0 B=1 C=2 etc) It also checks here column C for if it has "Sent" in it` meant to mention the value ? in my case, am looking to get the entire row/rows got inserted

Comment: also am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null (line 4, file "Code")`

Comment: You will need to change the sheet name from "Sheet1" 
To do the whole row, if you change the ```var bodyVal``` to ```sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,2).getValues();``` - this will insert the whole row to the email with each cell separated by a comma.  You can change the last number (2) to how many columns you want to include.