# how do I reset the google sheets counter?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, tabs

Current function: Using apps script, I delete a few tabs then add a few tabs. So new a new sheet is like 'Sheet 467'. The number is getting big very quickly even though there are only 8 sheets in the file.
Desired function: I'd like to reset the sheet counter so the next sheet is 9 (number of sheets currently in the file +1) rather than 468 (number of sheets there have ever been in the file +1).

I tried to google this but I think the search terms are too generic. I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: could you provide a snippet of the function you are writing?

Comment: I don’t really think this requires any script. The OP is just asking the question can you reset the sheet counter when you create a new Sheets so that it starts back and Sheet 1 again. I’ve often wondered that myself and I don’t know the answer.

Comment: You might try requesting it as a feature

Comment: I posted a workaround which I believe it will help you achieve your goal. @Cooper let me know what you think.

Comment: It’s an OK workaround but I prefer to be able to reset it back to one

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Unfortunately, this is the default behaviour of how sheets are created. You can request it as a feature but I don't think this will ever be implemented.

However, I would like to propose the following two workarounds:

**User inserts a new sheet:**

- Take advantage of the [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) trigger and especially the event
  object property `changeType`. When you add a new sheet, the latter
  takes the value of `INSERT_GRID`.
- This allows you to trigger a piece
  of code when a new sheet is added by the user.
- The following script will check whether you created a new sheet. If you did, it will rename the last created sheet as `Sheet` plus the total number of sheets.

**Script inserts a new sheet:**

If the new sheets are created by a script the `onChange` trigger can't be used. Then use the second solution I propose.

### Workarounds:

**Solution when the user inserts a new sheet:**

```
function nameNewSheet(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
    sheets[sheets.length-1].setName(`Sheet${sheets.length}`)
  }
}
```

In order to use this solution you have to create an **installable `onChange` trigger** for the `nameNewSheet` function. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65220821/11225291) on how to do that.

---

**Solution when the script inserts a new sheet:**

If the script itself adds new sheets, then `onChange` won't be triggered. But you can incorporate the following two lines into your existing script that inserts new sheets in order to rename the last created sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  //
  // the code of the script that adds a new sheet
  // 
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  sheets[sheets.length-1].setName(`Sheet${sheets.length}`);
}
```

---

### Illustration:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate it. I already rename the sheet. I'm hoping to reset that default sheet count, but maybe it's not possible as you say.